# Link gcloud with existing components

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, kubectl

After installing `gcloud`, running `gcloud components list` list all installed component.
Is there a way to associate `kubectl` (already install on the system using OS package manager) to this list?

`gcloud` handles 4 major versions of `kubectl`. This is convenient when you need to switch from one version to another (for testing purpose as long as `kubectl` versions are backward compatible). You can see it like a kind of SDKMan, or NVM. B
My OS package manager is installing `kubectl` even when I don't ask it as it's a dependency for `kubeadm`. So if I want to have `kubeadm` and `gcloud` handling several versions of my `kubectl` I have just a conflict (resolved by `path` precedence so `kubectl` from `~/google-cloud-sdk/bin` will never be used).

Cheers,
Olivier

Answer (score 0):

It's likely easiest to uninstall `kubectl` from your OS and then `gcloud components install kubectl` but what benefit do you seek from the association?

Apart from having `gcloud` report `kubectl` from `gcloud components list` and update it with `gcloud components update`, the only linkage (to my knowledge) is after `gcloud container clusters get-credentials ...` which, depends on `gcloud` to support authentication against Kubernetes Engine clusters. But, you may get this without using `gcloud` bundling of `kubectl`.

Otherwise, if your OS package manager is managing `kubectl` for you, I'd be inclined to not break it.

Comment: `gcloud` handles 4 major versions of `kubectl`. This is convenient when you need to switch from one version to another (for testing purpose as long as `kubectl` versions are backward compatible). You can see it like a kind of SDKMan, or NVM. But, sorry I forgot that in my first message... my OS package manager is installing `kubectl` even when I don't ask it as it's a dependency for `kubeadm`. So if I want to have `kubeadm` and `gcloud` handling several versions of my `kubectl` I have just a conflict (resolved by `path` precedence so `kubectl` from `~/google-cloud-sdk/bin` will never be used).

Comment: Aha! Interesting. Unfortunately, I don't know how you can associate a pre-existing `kubectl` with `gcloud`. Hopefully someone else can help you out.